# Modify an element in a nested dict given a "path" to it

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Given a "path" of a list of indices (of an arbitrary length) and a nested Python `list`/`dict` object, how can I write to the part of the object at a list?

For example, this might be my object (it's loaded from a JSON file):

```
data = {"dogs":[{"tail": True, "properties":{"test":1}}]}
```

and my list of indices might look like `["dogs", 0, "properties"]`.

If I want to retrieve the value at the path, I can do something like this:

```
>>> data = {"dogs":[{"tail": True, "properties":{"test":1}}]}
>>> path = ["dogs", 0, "properties"]
>>> mydata = data
>>> for i in path:
...     mydata = mydata[i]
...
>>> mydata
{'test': 1}
```

But say I want to modify the object at the path *inside the whole structure*? The above code is pass-by-value, not by reference, so I don't think I can reuse that. What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be probably a good alternative option, but I find [`jsonpath-rw`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpath-rw) library a good way to navigate and search inside a JSON structure:

```
>>> from jsonpath_rw import jsonpath, parse
>>> 
>>> data = {"dogs":[{"tail": True, "properties":{"test":1}}]}
>>> 
>>> jsonpath_expr = parse("dogs.[0].properties")
>>> jsonpath_expr.find(data)[0].value['test'] = 2
>>> print(data)
{'dogs': [{'tail': True, 'properties': {'test': 2}}]}
```

---

Note that you still have the "by reference" behavior in the code you've shown:

```
>>> data = {"dogs":[{"tail": True, "properties":{"test":1}}]}
>>> 
>>> path = ["dogs", 0, "properties"]
>>> mydata = data
>>> for i in path:
...     mydata = mydata[i]
... 
>>> mydata["test"] = 2
>>> print(data)
{'dogs': [{'tail': True, 'properties': {'test': 2}}]}
```

Comment: I don't want to introduce an external dependance, but I'll try your second example.

Comment: @LukeTaylor yeah, but note that assinging `mydata` to any value would not update the `data` dictionary. It would just "repoint" the `mydata` variable.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting behavior

Comment: @LukeTaylor well, it is logical though, `mydata` is sort of a "pointer" to an object, which is in our case sits inside `data`. If we update the object via `mydata['test'] = 2`, we see the change reflected in the `data` object since `mydata` is a reference. But, if we reassign `mydata` to something else, e.g. `mydata = {"new": "object"]`, we just repoint it to a new object..hope it makes sense to you. Sorry, I'm terrible at explaining things :)

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks for the extra explanation.